# Touch a UIButton and show Unity on UIView or UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, unity-game-engine

I read several answers on the Unity forum, including here and only show how to create a subclass and present my first UIViewController.

```
- (void)createViewHierarchyImpl
{
    homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    //_rootView = _unityView;
    _rootView = homeViewController.view;

    //_rootController = [[UnityDefaultViewController alloc] init];
    _rootController = homeViewController;
}
```

So far, so good.
The problem is that there are no examples for the new version of the Unity plugin that generates XCode, to show a UIViewController with Unity.

```
-(void)goToUnity:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"touch the button is OK");

    UIViewController *app = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UnityView" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:app animated:YES];
}
```

Thus, nothing happens. 
Is there any way to call the Unity in "default" mode Xcode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read an read and read many times, test and erros many times, i finally do! Touch a UIButton and open or do whatever you imagine with it.
I will share here for those who need a more complete code.
Getting Started:
You need to create your own main file .h and .m to be "overruled" the Unity automatically:

**mainAppController.h**

```
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "iPhone_View.h"

@interface mainAppController : UnityAppController
{
    UnityAppController  *_unityAppController;
}

- (void)createViewHierarchyImpl;

@end
```

You have to import this H headers to controll Unity stuffs.

**mainAppController.m**

```
#import "mainAppController.h"

@implementation mainAppController

-(void)createViewHierarchyImpl
{
    if(_unityAppController == nil)
    {
        _unityAppController = [[UnityAppController alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Unity Controller was set NICE!!!!");
    }
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadMain" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneMain" bundle:nil];
    }

    UIViewController *mainVC = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.rootViewController = mainVC;

    _rootController = [self.window rootViewController];
    //_rootController.wantsFullScreenLayout = TRUE;
    _rootController.edgesForExtendedLayout = TRUE;

    _rootView       = _rootController.view;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

@end

IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(mainAppController) //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!!!
```

This last line is the Unity which will "read" and use.

So, see, I used the storyboard, so I have more control over the navigation visually. But you can use whatever you want.

In another any UIViewController, I'll call the Unity, as follows:

**ShowARViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "iPhone_View.h"

@interface ShowARViewController : UIViewController
{
    UnityAppController *unityController;
    IBOutlet UIView *viewToUnity; // This is linked on Storyboard 
}
@end
```

**ShowARViewController.m**

```
#import "ShowARViewController.h"

@interface ShowARViewController ()

@end

@implementation ShowARViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    unityController = (UnityAppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [viewToUnity addSubview:unityController.unityView];
}
// more methods and codes...
@end
```

See, so I can have more control of Unity that I added in UIView and I can do what I want, for example, add a button above this view.

I hope I have helped really. 
If you have any questions or suggestions to make this code better, feel free to write me.

Regards

Comment: Hello i want to open unity AR view in my current view controller. I am doing the same. But app crashes say Unityview unrecognised selector sent to

Comment: @ios-developer what is your Unity version ?

Comment: I want to use the Xloudia AR. They provide support in unity. I have unity package and i export it as a Xcode project. Now i want to use it in my existing iOS project.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate unity Xcode project in objective c Xcode project?

Comment: Yes, this is what have here, what is your Unity version? It is Pro?

Comment: My unity version is 4.6.1. But can we directly drag and drop unity Xcode project into the objective c project or some different way we have to follow different steps to add?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70224/discussion-between-jack-loverde-and-ios-developer).

Comment: IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(ViewController)

I am getting this error, when I add the above line

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_AppControllerClassName", referenced from:
      +[ViewController(OverrideAppDelegate) load] in ViewController.o

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi @Lenin this post has 6 years. I doesnt work with Unity anymore. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the controller like this:

```
UIViewController* controller = [[UnityDefaultViewController] alloc] init];
```

Comment: Nothing happend, touch the button, but the view doesnt show up.
Trying to addSubview too, but i had "uncaught exception".
Any advice ? Thanks