# Unity: Call android function from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic("currentActivity");

activity.CallStatic("testMethod");
```

This is how I call Android static function without argument, and its works perfect. But I have issue when I'm trying to call non-static function with arguments.

I'm trying to call it like that:

```
activity.Call("testMethod", "testString");
```

But Android throws exception:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "L**myActivity**(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
```

What I do wrong ? What is the difference between static and non-static call ? I'm using the same activity. Here is my java method:

```
public void testMethod(String data) { }
```

**UPDATE**

Finally was able to run non static method:

```
activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
                                                                   {
                    activity.Call("testMethod", "testString");
            }));
```

That odd thats not working without runOnUIThread...Probably I did something wrong.

Comment: Can I see your native android code? Im having this same issue and Im not sure why you called currentActivity

Comment: what technological barriers stands between us and a more friendlier API to do this?

Answer (score 12):

While you might have fixed the issue, I believe the real issue lies elsewhere. I've helped create quite a few plugins for Unity, so I'm just going to put in my thoughts here for you to read and for anyone else who might face the same or similar issues.

Firstly, you've used a UIThread to call your non-static, public method. This is perfectly fine, but only if some UI operation is performed in the native code, such as showing a toast. Otherwise, the issue lies elsewhere.

Usually, if you create a method, it's going to be in a separate class that extends the `UnityPlayerActivity`. So for an example, let's say you've called it "MyClass.java"

This is probably how your Java Native class looks like

**Native Android Code**

```
package com.companyName.productName;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class MyClass extends UnityPlayerActivity {    

    public void testMethod(String data) { 
        Log.i("TAG", "The data was "+data);
    }
}
```

Now on the Unity side, your C# script should look like this

**Unity C# code**

```
AndroidJavaClass myClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.companyName.productName.MyClass");

myClass.Call("testMethod", new object[] { "testString" } );
```

Note how I've used the actual Java Class rather than the UnityPlayerActivity (i.e. "**com.companyName.productName.MyClass**" rather than "**com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer**")

Try the code above, it should print "**The data was testString**" to the logcat.

In your C# code, you've used the `currentActivity` field to call your method.

Rather, what you want to do is to create an `AndroidJavaObject` or `AndroidJavaClass` of your class that extends `UnityPlayerActivity` ("MyClass.java" in the above example) and call your methods.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Actually I'm using non-static method calling like yours.

Did you update your jar file under Assets/Plugins/Android?

Comment: I did. Finally I was able to run non static method. Check my update how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare testMethod(public) you in .jar file?

If you don't declare method, you try make .jar file.