# Is it possible to change an iOS and Android app's icon built in Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have read that [it is now possible to change an app's icon from Swift code](https://medium.com/swiftworld/swift-world-change-your-apps-icon-programmatically-in-ios-10-3-8e706a3206b3) for a natively built iOS app. I think [it's always been possible in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) for native apps as well. So I was wondering if there is some way to do this from Unity? Even if it's a bit hacky / janky would be happy to try it as long as it will be accepted by Apple for App Store submissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set icon before build, you can check [PlayerSettings.SetIconsForTargetGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetPlatformIcons.html).

But if you want to change app icon at runtime, I think you may call the native iOS/android method from Unity.

iOS: [Building Plugins for iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

android: [Unity: Call android function from Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550280/unity-call-android-function-from-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from Player setting respectively based on platform.

[image: Inspecter panel screen shot]