# Change Android statusbar color in Unity3D scene

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-statusbar

I want to define the Android statusbar color for a specific scene in Unity3D. Currently the bar is just black, but I want it to be gray like the background of my scene. I couldn't find any solution, so I hope that one of you maybe has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view it should be possible when combining these two statements: 
1. You can can call native Android Java code from inside Unity c# code, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550280/unity-call-android-function-from-unity) for example. 
2. In native Android you can set the status bar color programmatically, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/4958965) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the theme of the Unity app from AndroidManifest file. By changing the theme you automatically change the color of the status bar, you can even make it invisible.

Comment: Maybe provide an example (code of that AndroidManifest file) on how to change the theme and how to specify the color (or make it invisible).

Comment: Yes an example would be pretty nice. To get the status bar invisible would be the best thing for my case I guess :-)