# Calling Java methods in unity3d

Tags: java, android-studio, unity-game-engine

How do you properly import and use a .aar sdk in Unity3d. I am trying to use the Samsung sdk to know success.I have a built game that now needs to interact with the java methods inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity: Call android function from Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550280/unity-call-android-function-from-unity)

Comment: Yes and no but I could have been more precise. I created an empty unity3d project, made a dir under assets as Plugins and another in it as Android. I than drag n dropped the sdk/aar file into the android dir and marked it as android only plugin.How am I able to use the Java methods needed that are in the plugin?

Comment: Thank you of course