# Unity not Building and running game

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have started working in a Unity for last couple of days :) . I love the Android Studio(being as an Android Developer). But now I have to change the game a little bit , it seems like its an easy task but My Unity environment is not working properly.

Well I have installed the Unity 4.6 and a day beofre it was runing the game nicely. I have changed some coding , for example adding the ads and some other stuff and all went in the way as expected. But then, after some more specific work, I have noticed that Unity is not building the game and hence not running it on my device.

What is happening:

I dont know, as when I click to ctrl+b (to build and run) to run the project the building process starts and stops imediately showing no error in the log. So I deleted the game after back up move the game in the new directory delte some files as I was reading some help on the internet.

After doing that the project is now able to show me the error and it states that

> The animation state xyz could not be played because it could not be
>   found.

Where as I can see that this file is in assets folder.  I really do not know why it is still showing me this error. I have re Imported the assets many time but its not helping me out.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue , I know its compiler type error as far as I think (just from my experience from the Eclipse). Please suggest me a way to run my project.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24564470/2214693

Comment: Have you tried deleting the "Library" folder in your project?

Comment: nopes , what should I delete ?

Comment: you can simply pick your builded apk by selecting build and then run it on your device

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will that help but maybe you can try "Re-import all packages"....  I bumped into some problem same as your where I have the script/prefab but the Editor is throwing up some errors but I did not get the same error message as yours.