# Unity integrate to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile, integrate

I want to integrate my Unity game to my Android Studio project. I couldn't find any solution for that.I tried something but they are so old. They from 2014-2016. Nobody try this before? Have you any suggest for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564470/unity3d-and-android-studio-integration

Comment: Its not worked to me.