# cannot click on finish button when importing project

Tags: android, android-studio, import, apk, project

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4HL3.png)

When I try to import module in another project I cant click on finish button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import module in Android Studio Arctic Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636809/cant-import-module-in-android-studio-arctic-fox)

Answer (score 0):

The folder you want to import should contain a Gradle file in itself for Android Studio to recognise.
Can you check if that folder `Little Genius` has a Gradle file in it?

If it has a Gradle file, you would see a section like this to name the module.

[image]

The Finish button would be enabled after that.

Comment: It is a Unity based project and I was doing it by the following steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138926/16190312.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. So basically it is telling the same. You need the folder to be imported to have a Gradle file.
Since unity projects do not have that, that guy seems to have imported the project in Android Studio. (IMPORTED PROJECT not MODULE).

Comment: Yeah, I did it. The project got a gradle file created. But when i go to my project where i want to have this apk, It shows no gradle and I cant click on finish button.

Comment: I think you are choosing the wrong option from `File > New` menu. You might be selecting `New module`, but you should probably select `Import module`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens on Android Studio Arctic Fox version. I downloaded Intellij Idea, open project, file > new > module. That's works;
[image]

[image]